# Neyman smooth type of tests, questions about the orthogonal expansion

Tags: goodness-of-fit

In goodness-of-fit tests, we would like to check if given data $(X_1, \dots, X_N)$ has a distribution $f$. We do this by writing an orthogonal expansion $$f_K(x,a) := \frac{f(x)}{c(a)}\text{exp}\left(\sum_{i=1}^K a_i \psi_i(x)\right),$$ where $c(a)$ is just a normalization term.

We test the null hypothesis that $\left(a_1, \dots, a_K\right) = \vec{0}$, vs obviously the alternative that some $a_i$ is not zero.

I have several questions regarding to the alternative. The first is what type of expansion is this? I would have thought that an 'expansion' of $f$ would look like $f = \sum \langle f, \psi_i \rangle \psi_i$, and then we simply truncate it. In [here](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/uADA/12/lectures/ch17.pdf) (top of page 325), the author used 'embed' instead (write it as a more general family of functions), is this what expansion means?

The second is that what type of densities would be captured by the alternative? Can any density be written in the shape of $f_K(x,a)$, say if we let $K \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\} $? Does it differ if we consider the truncated case?